# ASP.net MVC2 File upload control for a separate progress bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, progress-bar

I would like to find out if there are any good controls available whereby I can upload files (upto 2GB) in a .net mvc2 application. The main issue is that I want to be able to retrieve the upload progress information from this control and have my own progress bar (which is already used in the application for other purposes) to display this information. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is a popular plugin. You may also [checkout an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444955/how-to-use-the-plupload-package-with-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: I checked out the above example in detail. Its a mashup of csharp, JScript, Silverlight and php other than flash and html5 solutions. Do you know something that is more of a .net only solution? It can have JScript or JQuery but not a complete mashup of 5 or 6 technologies.

Comment: @Ali, the standard solution is to place a simple `<input type="file">` tag and upload. There is no progressbar though. You will need to implement it yourself. The good thing about plupload is that it detects which of those technologies are available to the client and fallbacks progressively.

Comment: this worked great and using Plupload, I was able to do the above tasks.