# Progress bar while uploading the image in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, progress-bar

I want to display the Progress bar while uploading the image in ASP.NET MVC3.

Please suggest me how i can do that .

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use a client plugin. [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is one possible choice. And [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444955/how-to-use-the-plupload-package-with-asp-net-mvc/4447694#4447694) of how you could integrate it in your MVC application. Another popular plugin which supports this functionality is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: Personally I'd recommend "Uploadify" pretty flexible.

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad, yes `Uploadify` is pretty nifty plugin.