# How to upload files with plupload and asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I am wondering how do I upload files with asp.net mvc 3 and plupload plugin

I tried HttpPostedFileBase but it seems to be always null;

I found this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444955/how-to-use-the-plupload-package-with-asp-net-mvc)  but I am wondering if there are new ways for asp.net mvc 3.

I am also not 100% sure what is going on this. Is it actually saving the file to the server(App_data) as I do not want this. I am trying to upload icals and then extract the values from the icals and import them into by db.

Then get rid of the file. So I rather not be saving it to the server if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your form contains `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "home", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

And have your input name

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

The same on the controller

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Comment: right it would be file for parameter. So Does the HttpPostedFileBase wait for all the chunks to arrive? Or will I get incomplete files? I am also wondering is there away to send all the files at once(say if I upload 3 files it sends all 3 at once)? Would I have to disable multiple chuncking or something? I tried to do a collection for HttpPostedFileBase but that did not do anything as I think it is sending them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
         // General settings
         runtimes: 'silverlight',
         url: '/Home/Upload',
         max_file_size: '10mb',
         chunk_size: '1mb',
         unique_names: true,
         multiple_queues: false,

         // Resize images on clientside if we can
         resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

         // Specify what files to browse for
         filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
        ],

         // Silverlight settings
         silverlight_xap_url: '../../../Scripts/upload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
      });

      // Client side form validation
      $('form').submit(function (e) {
         var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

         // Files in queue upload them first
         if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
               if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                  $('form')[0].submit();
               }
            });

            uploader.start();
         } else {
            alert('You must queue at least one file.');
         }

         return false;
      });
```

And in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(  ) {
          HttpPostedFileBase FileData = Request.Files[0];

          if ( FileData.ContentLength > 0 ) {
             var fileName = Path.GetFileName( FileData.FileName );
             var path = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath( "~/Content" ), fileName );
             FileData.SaveAs( path );
          }

          return "Files was uploaded successfully!";
       }
```

That's all...No chunk is needed in Controller...

Comment: Chunking is needed if the file is larger than 1mb. .NET will throw `Maximum request length exceeded.`

Comment: why u set it as false `multiple_queues: false,` it has to be true if multiple files need to upload and accordingly server side method code need to be different to handle multiple files. thanks