# ASP.Net MVC 3 big file uploader with progress

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, progress

I've spent several hours of googling. Can anybody point me to an example of big file uploader with progress with backend on ASP.Net MVC3. I found many different solutions, but most of them use PHP as backend, and it's a bit hard for me to convert. Also I think there have to be some examples for ASP.Net MVC3.

PS I don't consider paid components, please don't suggest them.

Comment: I found my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444955/how-to-use-the-plupload-package-with-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploadify - there you have it :)
Set maxRequestLength in the web.config

http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx

Comment: I saw this example. Maybe I don't understand something, I didn't try to use it. But from the code it looks like, that it will not be showing progress and plug-in is used only to make the to be uploaded without postback. I need to upload 200mb files, so I have to give visual progress and upload with chunks.

Comment: After all, this aproach suited me best. With testing I found, that it still can show upload progress even when not actually transmitting in chunks. And this plug-in was the easiest to configure. Though I had to remove authentication from Upload handler, but this is ok, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [Telerik Upload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload) not sure what the file size limit is though.

This is a free and opensource component from Telerik.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll check it out. Thought that Telerik was paid.

Comment: most telerik stuff is paid, their mvc stuff is open source, but unless your application is open source as well you'll need to pony up for the commercial license.

Comment: There are situations you can use them without the license fee and without being open source as per my understanding when I read the license.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a good amount of time getting the right plugin too.

I use this :
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Uploadify uses flash to send files, which was bad for me as i needed upload from authenticated users ONLY. And flash would not send the cookies and so your application will treat the upload request as anonymous. If that is not an issue, uploadify works fine too.

Here is how i implemented it in mvc3 -

Create a controller / action to receive the opload file.
Change the 'action' property of the plugin to point to it -

```
// url of the server-side upload script, should be on the same domain
action: '/controller/action'
```

Make sure that action returns JSON object with a property in it with 'success' = 'true'/'false'

Comment: Flash/HTML5 is no problem, this is a local application, that can be dependend on particular technology, but I would really like to see ASP.Net MVC 3 backend example for this. And your link have PHP backend.

Comment: Look at the edit above. there is nothing PHP about the plugin it can use either backend, all it does is create an HTTP post request to the server