# File Upload as Part of Form with Other Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET MVC website. I need a page where the user must enter several fields, including an image file.

I could find many, many references for uploading a file using MVC. But they don't upload the file as part of a form with other fields.

Ideally, fields and file will be sent to a single controller. Any tips?

Comment: Are you using an ajax call or submit the form directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [FineUploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader). [See Demo](http://fineuploader.com/)

[Valums Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). It uses pure Javascript (uploads file using Iframe)

You might need to use a client plugin. [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is one possible choice. And [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444955/how-to-use-the-plupload-package-with-asp-net-mvc/4447694#4447694) of how you could integrate it in your MVC application. Another popular plugin which supports this functionality is [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

[Asp.net mvc 3 file uploads using the fileapi](http://buildstarted.com/2011/07/17/asp-net-mvc-3-file-uploads-using-the-fileapi/)

See Progress Demo 1, 2 & 3 at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Ref: [http://forums.asp.net/t/1897410.aspx/1?MVC4+File+Upload](http://forums.asp.net/t/1897410.aspx/1?MVC4%20File%20Upload)

Answer (score 11):

If you do not use third party libraries, try this:

Model

```
public class Strategy 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] File { get; set; }

    }
```

View

```
 @model TEST.Model.Strategy
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Strategy", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmStrategy", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
            <input id="templateFile" name="templateFile" type="file"  />
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)

        }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Strategy model, HttpPostedFileBase templateFile)
        {


            if (templateFile != null && templateFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    var fname = Path.GetFileName(templateFile.FileName);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                      templateFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                      byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
                      model.File = array;
                    }
                    ...
```

Comment: I think it's not necessary the File property in the Strategy model.

Comment: That's right, is not necessary or required. It's just an example ... For example if you persist the file in a table, and use some ORM ...