# Uploading image as part of a form ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that has input fields and file upload field, I think that I have done everything but I have a problem with the binary reader.
Model:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public byte[] EventPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Event events, [Bind(Exclude = "EventPhoto")]EventController model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var database = new EventSpotDbContext())
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["EventPhoto"];

                using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);
                }
            }
            events.EventPhoto = imageData;
            database.Events.Add(events);
            database.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
    }
    return View(events);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" , role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EventName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventPhoto)
   <input type="file" name="Event" id="fileUpload" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />

   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
}
```

On post Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Line 83:                         using (var binary = new >BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))

Comment: Check 2nd answer. Possible duplicate of [File Upload as Part of Form with Other Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128196/file-upload-as-part-of-form-with-other-fields)

Comment: What problem? Doesn't compile? What is an error?

Comment: What problem? What are you expecting to happen. What actually happens? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Server Error in '/' ApplicationObject reference not set to an instance of an object..
Source Error: 
Line 92:                         HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["EventPhoto"];
Line 93: 
Line 94:                         using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))
Line 95:                         {
Line 96:                             imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);

It needs to save the image in the DB in a column in Events table

Comment: Edit you question with the error (not in comments) and include the view. (clearly your view is not correct since its not sending the file in the request)

Comment: Because your file input is named `Event` (not `EventPhoto`) so its `HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["Event"];` But this is awful practice. Use a view model which includes a property `public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }` and in the view `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Photo, new { type="file", accept="..." })` to bind to you model and post back that model.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know an easy way to fetch and display the stored photo that will work with my code?

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question (and read the help files first)