# ASP.NET MVC : View stored image as byte[] from Db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have stored the image in a column of a table alongside with other information , but i have troble displaying the image when retrieving the whole information about the post. 
I am getting 'broken img' icon.

Model:

```
public class Event
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string EventName { get; set; }
public byte[] EventPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

Create Action:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Event events, [Bind(Exclude = "EventPhoto")]EventController model)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var database = new EventSpotDbContext())
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["EventPhoto"];

                using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);
                }
            }
            events.EventPhoto = imageData;
            database.Events.Add(events);
            database.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
    }
return View(events);
}
```

Input view:

```
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EventPhoto)
   <input type="file" name="Event" id="fileUpload" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />
```

Display Action:

```
  public ActionResult DisplayImg(Event events)
    {
        var bdEvents = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<EventSpotDbContext>();
        var userImage = bdEvents.Users.Where(x => x.Id == (events.Id).ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        return new FileContentResult(events.EventPhoto, "image/jpg");
    }
```

Display View:

```
<div class="container">
<article>

    <p> @Model.EventName </p>
    <img src="@Url.Action("DisplayImg", "Event" )" />

</article>
```

Any solution to my problem?

Comment: Your `@Url.Action("DisplayImg", "Event" )` does not pass any data to the `DisplayImg()` method and your `Event events` paremeter is just a default instance - the value of `EventPhoto` is `null`! But that method should never contain a parameter which is a model anyway - its needs to be (say) `int ID` where `ID` is the identifier of the `Event`, and you get the `Event` from the database. (and if you did try to pass the properties of `Event` to that method, it would certainly throw an exception because of the query string limit)

Comment: Did you bother to read the comment - your still not passing anything to the method!

Comment: sorry, it was a typo here in the post, but i had fixed this in the code, but still not working.
is this how it needs to be :        <img src="@Url.Action("DisplayImg", "Model.Id" )" />
?

Comment: That does not pass anything to your method! - its `@Url.Action("DisplayImg, new { id = Model.Id })`

Comment: now I am displaying not an image, not a broken icon, but a  /Event/DisplayImg/9 :D , there must be something else too

Comment: Now you have deleted your `<img>` tag!!

Comment: And stop changing your original question (which just invalidates all the comments/answers). Append any new code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing your `DisplayImg` action expects an `Event` parameter, so try sending one. You're sending a string right now. Try this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("DisplayImg", Model)" />
```

An even better solution is to just pass the ID of the event entry, by sending `Model.Id` and receiving an `int` that you use for the lookup.

However, the `DisplayImg` function you wrote is also off, you're using the `Id` property of the argument to look up the image, then you return the `EventPhoto` field instead. You should be returning the image you looked up.

That's as much as I can tell you without actual request/response data dumps. "Broken image" is about as useful a debugging aid as milk. Don't throw milk at your computer to fix bugs please.

Comment: I have edited my code and the post here, but the result is the same? Any other advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<file>` attribute is called `Event` but you're trying to access the file using `Request.Files["EventPhoto"]`.

You should be using the name that you have specified for it within the view:

```
Request.Files["Event"]
```

Comment: I think you will find that's just a typo from OP's [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204031/uploading-image-as-part-of-a-form-asp-net-mvc) :)

Comment: I think the OP needs to find an example for the use of `HttpPostedFileBase` too

Comment: Yes, I noted that they should be using a view model with a property for that in their previous question.